# Flutter Force State to have certain Mixin

Tags: flutter, dart, mixins

I have a mixin (`MyMixin`) that I apply in the state of some widgets like this:

```dart
    class MyStfulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyStfulWidget State createState() => _MyStfulWidget State();
    }
    
    class _MyStfulWidget State extends State<MyStfulWidget> with MyMixin { ... }
```

I sometimes need to pass this stateful widgets as a parameter for a method (`MyMethod`)

```dart
    void myMethod(Widget myWidget) { ... }
```

The problem with the following method is that it accepts every kind of widgets. If I pass a widget that does not have a MyMixin it will not work properly...

Is there any way to *force* the "myWidget" parameter to be a stateful widget that contains a mixin in its state?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you said you passed `StatefulWidget` to `MyWidget` method but `MyMixin` is on its `State` and `State` is private so this is impossible in this case.
In context of your `MyMixin` you should mix it on `StatefulWidget` itself and change the prototype of method to

```dart
void myMethod<T extends MyMixin>(T widget);
```